# Linear algebra with Dirac notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, linear-algebra, quantum-states

I have some questions about linear algebra. Let's say $\{|v_1 \rangle, |v_2 \rangle, |v_3 \rangle \}$ are orthonormal basis of the $\mathcal{V}(\mathbb{C})$. Then, let's define two vectors 
$$ |a \rangle = 2i |v_1 \rangle - |v_ \rangle + 4 |v_3 \rangle \\ |b \rangle = |v_1 \rangle +3i |v_2 \rangle - |v_3 \rangle $$

My questions are:

**1.** Is it correct?

$$  \langle a|b \rangle = -2i \langle v_1|v_1 \rangle - 3i \langle v_2|v_2\rangle - 4 \langle v_3|v_3 \rangle = -2i - 3i -4 = -4 - 5i $$

or should there be some more expression above?

**2.** Does product of two kets $ |a\rangle|b\rangle$ make sens?

In my opinion no, because kets are columns and product of columns like that's is indefinite. But maybe I'm wrong and there is better explanation?

**3.** Does sum $ |\rangle + \langle| $ make sense?

Same as above. Bra is a row and ket is a column, so it's impossible to sum them.

Can somebody tell me if I'm wrong or explain **2.** and **3.** more *mathematically*?

Comment: 1.When you turn a ket into a bra you have to conjugate the coefficients of the basis kets.

Answer (score 4):

For question $\mathbf{1}$ you're right: by using the orthonormality relation

$$\langle v_i | v_j \rangle= \delta_{ij} $$

you'll only get the scalar product of the same vectors since they give you zero with the others.

Question $\mathbf{2}$ is a little bit more complicated: the product $$|a\rangle|b\rangle$$ makes sense whenever the intended product is the [*tensor product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product). If we wanted to be precise we would make it clear by writing it as

$$ |a\rangle\otimes |b\rangle \equiv |a\rangle|b\rangle$$

This kind of product comes all the time, for example, when talking about system of particles. If you want to go deeper with an example search for *addition of angular momentum* on every QM book. For a deeper argument you can look up [Fock space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space) which is a fundamental concept in the quantum treatment of systems of many particles such as quantum field theories.

The last question it's easy: that sum makes no sense. Broadly speaking a *ket* is a vector in some Hilbert space while a *bra* is a functional acting on that Hilbert space. This means that a *bra* belongs to the **dual** of that Hilbert space. In this sense you clearly cannot add them since they do not belong to the same space to begin with.

Moreover I wanted to add that, while a it is a good way to think as bra and kets as row and column vectors, this is only one possible representation, the simples one. More abstractly a ket is an element of a certain Hilbert space with some properties and the bra is an element of the dual space. The two spaces are connected to one another thanks to [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you said, but now I wonder about something similiar. I got why we can't sum _bra_ and _ket_ since they belong to the different space.

But, why we can calculate the inner product of them like $ \langle a | b \rangle $ ? It doesn't matter here that's _bra_ and _ket_ don't belong to the same space?

Comment: @pepe The scalar product $(\quad,\quad)$ is inherited by the Hilbert space. With that you can define bras from their vectors in the Hilbert space: for every vector $|\psi\rangle\in H$ you can define a ket as $\langle\phi| = (\phi,\cdot)$. In this manner you can see that $\langle\phi|$ is a linear functional that can be applied on a ket as $$\langle\phi|(\psi) = (\phi, \psi) \equiv \langle\phi|\psi\rangle$$ All of this comes from the statement of Riesz representation theorem that tells us that every linear functional on an Hilbert space can be represented in a unique way with the inner product.